# medfilt2 откуда импортировать?

Tags: фильтр

Мне нужно выполнить медианную фильтрацию, хочу использовать для этого medfilt2. Никак не могу найти, откуда делаем import этой функции, чтобы она работала. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

```
import scipy
scipy.signal.medfilt2d
```